# Internet Explorer 8 still edit html in Expression?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-8, microsoft-expression

In previous versions I could click an edit button on the toolbar and open up a copy of the web page I was viewing in a specified HTML Editor.

Can I still do this-with one click-in IE 8?

I have set my preferred editor to Expression 4:

[image]

I see that I can hit f12 (for Developer tools) which opens up a built in editor, and then I can save the web page and the open up that web page with expression-but I'd like to do this in one step as I could with earlier versions of IE.

Is this still possible in IE 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File --> Edit in Expression 4